# How do I force DOM to update/refresh just before and after an ajax query?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, asynchronous, refresh

I'm having a browser issue with my Busy icon. The code looks like this:

```
$("#busysymbol").show();
$("#busysymbol").position({my:"right top",at:"right top",of:$("#datepicker"),offset:"-3 3"});
var resp = $.ajax({url: "book_ajax.php?req=daysformonth&month=1",
        cache: false,
        async: false
        }).responseText;
$("#busysymbol").hide();
var daysInMonth = resp.split(",");
...etc...
```

This code works perfect in Firefox however in Chrome and Safari the busy symbol is not showing. I believe Chrome and Safari are caching up the changes to the DOM and the $("busysymbol").show() call is not immediately refreshing.

Is there a way I can force Chrome/Safari to update the display.

Comment: before `$("#busysymbol").hide();` do `alert('Hello')` and see what happens

Comment: Adding alert('Hello') indeed forces the $("#busysymbol") to show. Which is good because it proves that the program flow is correct, however, if the alert isn't there, the DOM update doesn't occur, busy symbol stays hidden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe try using [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop) global events for your busy symbol.
For example:

```
$("#busysymbol").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();
});
$("#busysymbol").ajaxStop(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

at the beginning of your code, and remove the hiding and showing from your specific .ajax() handlers.

Oh, I've just noticed that you are using **synchronous** requests, so it's not even AJAX – more like SJAX. Do you have some very good reason to completely block the user interface of your browser while you're waiting for the request to either complete or timeout? If not then try using something like this:

```
$("#busysymbol").hide();
$("#busysymbol").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();
});
$("#busysymbol").ajaxStop(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
var resp = $.ajax({url: "book_ajax.php?req=daysformonth&month=1",
        cache: false,
        success: function (resp) {
            var daysInMonth = resp.split(",");
            ...etc...
        }
});
```

(not tested)

Try if it works without repositioning the #busysymbol and then try to add the correct positioning at the very beginning. Keep in mind that `.position()` doesn't take arguments so that longest line in your code wasn't actually doing anything – see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/position). What you need is `.offset()` or `.css()`.

Comment: Hi rsp, thanks for yours suggestion. It seems to be an issue with the synchronous request. I add the ajaxStart() and ajaxStop() to the $("#busysymbol") and it works great for all the other asynchronous queries on the page but not for the Synchronous one (Well, with Safari and Chrome anyway, Firefox seems OK).

Comment: Can't think of a way to get around the synchronous. The ajax is used in a function which returns values, need the ajax to finish so that the function can return.

Comment: It's interesting that you mention .position() doesn't take any arguments.<br>I went to http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/ when looking up the function<br>These docs say that there are several arguemetns, and I have seen evidence of this function working in all browsers.

Comment: @user631798: Those arguments to .position() is a [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) extension which doesn't work in plain [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). You didn't mention that you're using jQuery UI but if you do then you can use it. Just make sure to include jQuery UI in your page and it should work fine. I would still advice to try if it works without repositioning the #busysymbol and if it works then try to add the correct positioning at the very beginning.

Comment: @user631798: The synchronous XHR requests cause a lot of problems, one of which is what you are experiencing, another one is that you are blocking the entire user interface of your page for the time of your request, which may not be an issue for you right now during the development, but your users will notice it in production and think that their browser hanged or your website is broken. You don't have to block while waiting for the response, this is what callbacks are for. Use your data in the callback when it is available. Try to use something similar the example that I provided.

Comment: Update: note that as of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document. I'm currently using jQuery 1.11.2 and this was the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think Chrome and Safari is executing your Ajax request synchronously, despite `aynch` flag. To get around that, you could hide the icon in a callback of ajax function like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'book_ajax.php?req=daysformonth&month=1',
  success: function(data) {

    $("#busysymbol").hide();

  }
});
```

Comment: note: the guy has "async: false" so that is telling it to do it synchronously.  so they are doing it because of async flag, not despite it.